# Generate NPM Audit into a Json file

Tags: node.js, json, npm

I haven't see any post about this question. What I'm planning to do is to generate `npm audit` into json file, but I will only generate the list of packages with high or critical severity.

`npm audit -audit-level=critical` I saw the document this is the way to check for audit with severity is critical. And I know there is a command to generate json directly in the terminal is `npm audit -json`. I combined both:

`npm audit -audit-level=critical -json`

This works great, it show json in the terminal, but with except that I cannot scroll all the way up to read all of them. Plus I need to write a javascript that look through data of json file of audit. So is there a way to write a json file for `npm audit` ?

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Linux you can redirect the output to a file like this:

```
npm audit -audit-level=critical -json > audit.json
```

[More information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)

Comment: That was very helpful! Thank you very much, I'm learning new npm command today --- I'm just a junior dev, so this really helped

Comment: The same command works in Powershell on Windows systems, as well